# Elasticsearch Index red with no shards assigned

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using the ELK stack, and have an issue where my metricbeat index named `metricbeat-7.4.0-000001` has no assigned shards.

Information on my ELK stack:

- Elastic, Logstask, Kibana versions: 7.4.0 (I do intend on updating once I have everything running smoothly)
- **Single node** on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (I also intend on upgrading this soon - I started this project well before 20.04)
- 2 x Xeon E5-2620 (6 Core, 12 Threads @ 2GHz) with 64GB RAM
- System load averages 0.03 and RAM consumption sits just below 7GB, so I struggle to think the server's not performant enough for this.
- 1TB Disk space, 147 GB in use so I can't see it being disk consumption either

I have been struggling with this for a number of weeks, following countless tutorials and support pages, all to no avail. From what I can tell, this is a common issue if there is no disk space, or if the server does not have the memory / processing resources available.

Short of re-creating my cluster from the ground up, I feel that I have tried everything. Deleted indexes, re-imported ALL metricbeat config (Index Templates, Lifecycle Policies), re-routed (with and w/out retry-failed) more times than I can count. ILM Policies do seem to link up, but no shards assigned.

When re-creating the index templates, I stop logstash (to prevent any undesired index creations), export the json then re-import it in the Kibana Dev Tools. Then, I modify the index template only to change the Index Pattern to match my indexes, from the default `metricbeat-*` to `metricbeat-7.4.0-*`. My indexes are created with the pattern beatname-version-autoincrement such as `metricbeat-7.4.0-000001`

This has not been the only index to be giving me grief. I have had the same issues with a winlogbeat index and a heartbeat index, however I suspect that somehow, I have managed to fix this particular issue with them.

When I run an explain on allocation for this index, it tells me the following:

```
{
  "index" : "metricbeat-7.4.0-000001",
  "shard" : 0,
  "primary" : true,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "INDEX_CREATED",
    "at" : "2020-06-03T04:23:31.865Z",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no"
  },
  "can_allocate" : "no",
  "allocate_explanation" : "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "OQ3AFLyhRcao1z2es2p79w",
      "node_name" : "server.network.local",
      "transport_address" : "ipaddress:9300",
      "node_attributes" : {
        "rack_id" : "main",
        "ml.machine_memory" : "67501658112",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20"
      },
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "weight_ranking" : 1,
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "awareness",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "node does not contain the awareness attribute [main]; required attributes cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes=main]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I have assigned in my elasticsearch.yml `node.attr.rack_id: main` and this makes no difference. Being that this is a single node, however, I can't see why it struggles to identify where to assign it to, granted the lack of option.

My next suspicion was that maybe it just needed a little time to figure itself out. I read somewhere that Elasticsearch runs lifecycle policies every 15 minutes, and wonder if that may be involved in assigning shards? However, given all the patience in the world (or at least a few hours worth anyway), I found no change - I even restarted and waited until the next day, still to no avail.

More recently, I have re-created the index (many times over). This current one is only a couple of hours old and with a fresh index, still presents the same issue.

When I cat my shards, I get something which contains the following. I can see what I expect from heartbeat, but the metricbeat primary index shows no shards.

```
heartbeat-7.4.0-000001          0 p STARTED         0    283b ipaddress server.network.locak
heartbeat-7.4.0-000001          0 r UNASSIGNED                            
metricbeat-7.4.0-000001         0 p UNASSIGNED                            
metricbeat-7.4.0-000001         0 r UNASSIGNED
```

A comment removed version of my elasticsearch.yml below:

```
node.name: auditsvr.ctperth.local
node.attr.rack_id: main
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: ipaddress
discovery.seed_hosts: ["ipaddress"]
discovery.type: single-node
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: cert.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: cert.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: ca-cert.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: none
```

And the same for metricbeat:

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  index.codec: best_compression
setup.kibana:
  host: "http://server.network.local:80"
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["ipaddress:5044"]
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/metricbeat
  name: metricbeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644
setup.ilm.enabled: auto
setup.ilm.rollover_alias: "metricbeat"
setup.ilm.pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
```

My next step would be to start over, but I can only imagine this is a configuration issue, which means I need to start over again. I feel this requires someone a little more familiar with Elastic than I am, I can usually figure these things out but need a little direction with this one.

Appreciation in advance

**UPDATE**

As per Val's request, please find the metricbeat index template here:

https://sandbox.michael-thompson.net/StackOverflow/62169773/metricbeat-7.4.0%20Index%20Template.json

And the Cluster Settings here:

https://sandbox.michael-thompson.net/StackOverflow/62169773/clustersettingsincludedefaultstrue.json

Unfortunately, they were too large for pastebin.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post the `metricbeat-7.4.0-*` index template (especially the settings section)? You can remove the `node.attr.rack_id` setting from your `elasticsearch.yml` file as it's of no use in a single node install.

Comment: Can you also post what you get from `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true`?

Comment: Hi Val, I have had to link these externally because they are quite large - too large for pastebin, in fact. I have updated my original answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic cluster setting is the following one, any idea how it got there?

```
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "awareness" : {
            "attributes" : "main"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

So there are two ways to solve the situation. In both cases, you can remove the following setting from `elasticsearch.yml` as it's useless:

```
node.attr.rack_id: main
```

**Option A:**

You need to remove the following cluster setting, since it doesn't make sense with a single node setup. Just run:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes" : null
    }
}
```

**Option B:**

Leave the cluster setting and add the following node attributes to `elasticsearch.yml` so that the cluster setting (as it is) can make sense:

```
node.attr.main: whatever
```

Also, it would help if you read more about [cluster allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/allocation-awareness.html), because with a single node setup it doesn't really make sense to set it up.

Comment: Thanks Val, I have removed this setting as you recommended and it appears to have resolved my issue.

I did add that setting myself while following documentation on fixing another unallocated shard issue, but I believe I managed to resolve that and that it was likely unrelated. Of course, with no idea the can of worms I was opening. I'll look a little into that allocation. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Well that's more value than what I was looking for.  I never figured out why my indexes were yellow, now I have disabled replicas and everything is green. Thanks again!